# pure javascript toggle only once using data-getAttribute to to compare

Tags: javascript, html, css, toggle

I have some issues i can't understand why it's not toggling when I click on the button it's toggling only once...? And i can't hid the element!!! how it should work sick on first button it shows the element click again hide element!

[Link to jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Guntarwi/vognudc5/)

```js
//Short cuts
function $(e)
{
  return document.querySelector(e);
}

function $$(e)
{
    return document.querySelectorAll(e);
}
  // All elementis whit toggle-option class
var toggle = $$(".toggle-option");
 //Add EventListener to all buttons whit class toggle-option
for (var i = 0; i < toggle.length; i++)
{
  toggle[i].addEventListener('click', togller, false);
}

function togller()
{
  //clicked element's atribut valuve
  var current = this.getAttribute("data-toggle-number"),
    hidden = $$(".hidden");
  // looop to campare clicked elments's attribut's value whit hidden elements //value     
  for (var i = 0; i < hidden.length; i++)
  {
    var hiddenAtr = hidden[i].getAttribute("data-toggle-number");

    if (current == hiddenAtr)
    {
      if (hidden[i].hasAttribute("data-toggle-number"))
      {
        hidden[i].classList.toggle("hidden")

      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.search-bar {
   height: 50px;
   width: 50px;
   background-color: red;
 }
.add-task-bar {
   height: 50px;
   width: 50px;
   background-color: blue;
 }
 .hidden {
   display: none;
 }
```

```html
<button class="fa fa-search fa-lg search-btn toggle-option" data-toggle-number="1">Search</button>
<button class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-lg add-task-btn toggle-option" data-toggle-number="2">addTask</button>

<div class="hidden search-bar option" data-toggle-number="1"></div>
<div class="hidden add-task-bar option" data-toggle-number="2"></div>
```

Comment: Please spend some time fixing the typos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
hidden = $$(".hidden")
```

to

```
hidden = $$(".option")
```

Since class 'hidden' gets removed, it won't work anymore (but it still has class 'option'.)

Comment: Thx night coding xD xD xD

Comment: Can you litle bit help me and explane what i need to do to if i click on element the priwius elment closes..?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you mean?

Comment: show one element and hide other on click if you click on different buttons! if one element is opend i click on other button the opend element closes and new element opens!

Comment: Well, you could try:

`if(current == hiddenAtr){    
            if(hidden[i].hasAttribute("data-toggle-number")){
             hidden[i].classList.toggle("hidden");
             
            } 
           } else {
                 hidden[i].classList.add("hidden")
                }`

Have you considered using jQuery?

Comment: Here it works: https://jsfiddle.net/vognudc5/4/ - When one box is visible and the other one appears, the visible one disappears.

Comment: Aloso Thx i whill try to understand that code thx for all im glad that you helped me!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get the element through `.hidden` class to toggle but since hidden class is already toggled there will never be an element with the `.hidden` class to be retrieved. You shall access those elements with a common fixed class and that one happens to be the `.option` class. So change the line `hidden = $$(".hidden");` to `hidden = $$(".option");`

Besides accessing the data attributes are much easily and faster done through the dataset API. Please see the below code.

```js
    function $$(e) {
        return document.querySelectorAll(e);
      }
      // All elementis whit toggle-option class
    var toggle = $$(".toggle-option");
     //Add EventListener to all buttons whit class toggle-option
    for (var i = 0; i < toggle.length; i++) {
      toggle[i].addEventListener('click', togller, false);
    }

    function togller() {
      //clicked element's atribut valuve
      var current = this.dataset.toggleNumber,
        hidden = $$(".option");
      // looop to campare clicked elments's attribut's value whit hidden elements //value     
      for (var i = 0; i < hidden.length; i++) {
        var hiddenAtr = hidden[i].dataset.toggleNumber;
        if (current == hiddenAtr) {
          if (hidden[i].hasAttribute("data-toggle-number")) {
            hidden[i].classList.toggle("hidden")

          }
        }

      }
    }
```

```css
        .search-bar {
          height: 50px;
          width: 50px;
          background-color: red;
        }
        .add-task-bar {
          height: 50px;
          width: 50px;
          background-color: blue;
        }
        .hidden {
          display: none;
        }
```

```html
<button class="fa fa-search fa-lg search-btn toggle-option" data-toggle-number="1">Search</button>
<button class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-lg add-task-btn toggle-option" data-toggle-number="2">addTask</button>

<div class="hidden search-bar option" data-toggle-number="1"></div>
<div class="hidden add-task-bar option" data-toggle-number="2"></div>
```

And a simplified ES6 version of this code would be as folows. Note that since in the arrow functions `this` will remain bound to the enclosing context there is no need for `current` as `var current = this.dataset.toggleNumber;`

```js
function $$(e) {
  return document.querySelectorAll(e);
}

Array(...$$(".toggle-option")).forEach(e => e.addEventListener('click', togller, false));

function togller() {
  Array(...$$(".option")).forEach(e => {
  (e.dataset.toggleNumber == this.dataset.toggleNumber) &&
  e.classList.toggle("hidden")});
}
```

```css
        .search-bar {
          height: 50px;
          width: 50px;
          background-color: red;
        }
        .add-task-bar {
          height: 50px;
          width: 50px;
          background-color: blue;
        }
        .hidden {
          display: none;
        }
```

```html
<button class="fa fa-search fa-lg search-btn toggle-option" data-toggle-number="1">Search</button>
<button class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-lg add-task-btn toggle-option" data-toggle-number="2">addTask</button>

<div class="hidden search-bar option" data-toggle-number="1"></div>
<div class="hidden add-task-bar option" data-toggle-number="2"></div>
```